# Convergence of modified geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem:

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
> $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 0$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges if $|x| < 1$.
> 2. Prove that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \right) = 0$.
>
> Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n x^n (1 - x)$ where $s_n = a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$.

My reasoning for 1 is as follows: by the ratio test on $\sum a_n$, we must have $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1$. Then we apply the ratio test to $\sum a_n x^n$ to find that
$$ \lim \frac{a_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n} \leq \lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = x < 1. $$

For 2. I'm not sure what to do exactly. The equality in the hint is clear to me, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $a_n$ can vanish, the rati test doesn't work in this case.

The condition : $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to $0$ means that the radius of convergence of  $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is $\geq 1$ which means that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is perfectly defined when $|x|<1$.

For 2 i suggest you want to use the fact that $\sum _{k=0}^{n} a_k \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and   $N_0$ be an integer such that for all $N\geq N_0$ : $$|\sum _{n=0}^{N} a_n |\leq\epsilon$$

We have $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x) = \sum _{n=0}^{N_0} s_nx^n(1-x)+\sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x)$$

and we have :
$$|\sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x) |\leq \sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} |s_nx^n(1-x) | \leq \epsilon( \sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} x^n(1-x) ) \leq \epsilon $$

Therefore :

$$|\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x)|\leq \epsilon+\sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x)  $$

Now if we let $x$ be sufficiently close to $1$, the term  ( $\sum _{n=N_0+1}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x)  $)   will also be $\leq \epsilon $.

Therefore

Given that $x$ is sufficiently close to 1 the following estimate holds : $$|\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} s_nx^n(1-x)| \leq 2\epsilon $$

This is exactly :

$$lim _{x\rightarrow 1^- } \sum s_n x^n(1-x) = 0 $$